# HTML 5, linking with a div

Tags: css, html

At the moment I have a setup similar to this:

```
<a href="#">
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 20px;">
    <span>Blah</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Which works perfectly well in Chrome. It fails W3C validation, however - IE apparently has issues with it.

I've considered using JavaScript to do it, but I know a lot of older web-users disable JavaScript for security concerns (personally, I'd just stop using old versions of IE. the pains)

But I was wondering, what's the HTML5 approved way to do this?

Before anyone downvotes, I'd like to reiterate that I'm asking specific to HTML 5.

Comment: does the validation error have to do with the missing double quote on your inline style? And why would you not just make the link display block with the appropriate style?

Comment: Why `<div>` when you can just apply `display: block` on `<a>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just use CSS to make the anchor a block or inline block element so it can be given a height and width. Use either a CSS selector or an inline `style` attribute to assign `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, set the height and width, and get rid of the `div`.

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;width: 50px; height: 20px;">
    <span>Blah</span>
</a>
```

If you're not sure about block vs inline-block, there are lots of articles on the web. However, `block` elements exist on their own line (barring things like `float`), but may have a height and width (amongst other things). `inline-block` can also be assigned height and width, but can exist inline with other elements. Caveat, some browsers *cougholdversionsofIEcough* don't understand `inline-block` or have bugs with it (there are ways around that). `inline` (the default for `a`), technically can't be given a height or width. And obviously the insinuation here is you can make inline elements behave like block elements, and vise versa.

**EDIT**

As per the comments, here's a CSS hack to make `inline-block` work reasonably well for proper browsers and also IE7-8.

```
.my-inline-block-element {
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Good browsers will see `display` and use `inline-block`. IE7-8 will say WTF is that and do something stupid. But it'll see `zoom` which will trigger `hasLayout`, and because of a bug, it'll process `*display:inline` (but other browsers won't because `*` isn't allowed) and set display back to `inline`. But since we've got `hasLayout`, it'll now use the height and width but remain inline. Confused? Annoyed? Good... IE sucks.

Comment: Your edit was interesting actually. I used 'inline-block' without even thinking, as I'm building a horizontal menu. Looks like I am going to have to do some more research. Thanks very much!

Comment: Older versions of IE (I think 8 and less) don't know `inline-block`, but have bugs/incorrect rendering techniques where you can give them height and width provided something called `hasLayout` is triggered. See my edit for a hack that has served me reasonably well.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly valid HTML5 if you fix the missing quotation mark in your `style` attribute. Try putting this in the HTML5 validator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Something</title></head>
<body><a href="#">
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 20px;">
    <span>Blah</span>
  </div>
</a>
</body>
```

[image]